# How to change reply-to and return-path header with gmail smtp in django

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

I am using gmail smtp in my django website. I have a contact form where user put email and message then I send a mail to the admin with :

```
   email = EmailMessage('email subject', 'email message', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                        ['admin.mysite@gmail.com'],
                          headers = {'Reply-To': 'user@foo.bar',
                               'Sender': 'user@foo.bar','from': 'user@foo.bar','Return-Path': 'user@foo.bar'})
   email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

email is sent/received correctly but when admin client select reply in gmail, it always reply to the settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER and not the user address. On the email original header the From and Return-path are set with the setting.EMAIL_HOST_USER

Comment: Are you saying that you are sending the message through gmail's smtp server smtp.gmail.com?  And, when the recipient receives the message, the sender's address (and the reply to address) are showing as the gmail address associated with the gmail account that you are using to send the message through, instead of the sender address that you are specifying in your code?

Comment: Yes it is, some part of the header are ignored by smtp.gmail.com. I guess that it must be a security feature. I currently looking to use exim4 on my server instead of gmail

Comment: > I have the same problem for a year, due to the Gmail restriction.
>
> But today I retry and it works, it seems that Google changed its policy. ```python
# settings.py
....
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Infoma Admin<no-reply@infoma.co.nz>'
``` [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA5Zz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA5Zz.png) *Django 2.1.7*

Answer (score 6):

Google violates the RFPs defining the expected operation of an SMTP server, rewriting the headers. This may be the root cause of your problem: http://lee-phillips.org/gmailRewriting/

Comment: It's not just google... Amazon.de and many others aren't strict with the smtp 5321 address in SPF/DMARC alignment... it's fairly common and fine security wise. https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000902654-Mail-messages-with-different-smtp-mailfrom-and-from-do-not-pass-the-DMARC-filter-and-go-to-spam
Regardless GSuite/Workspace has no setting to fix it. So you're left with 3 options, change the primary address or add separate SMTP logins.

Answer (score 1):

If you use smtp.gmail.com to send a message, and the sender's email address is not yourgoogleemailname@gmail.com, then Gmail will rewrite the headers and set the from address to yourgoogleemailname@gmail.com.  See http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server for more info, and for a possible solution.

Comment: thank for reply but in my case I would like to dynamically modify the from or reply-to, because each user will send email through the same contact form, providing an input field with their email.

Comment: That's fine.  But, as noted above, if you send the message through smtp.gmail.com, then gmail will rewrite the headers, replacing the from address (and the reply-to address) with yourgoogleemailname@gmail.com.  If that's a show-stopper for you, then you might want to send these through a different outgoing SMTP server, such as SendGrid or UltraSMTP.com.

Comment: well actually I found the workaround, it s in fact a bug, I was sending my email with settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER wich is a gmail account linked with the admin.mysite@gmail.com. I just create another gmail account (not linked) and now the reply-to is working properly. In the main time I installed my own SMTP server with exim and understood the bug was related to the sending email addresse.