# How to send empty mail with phpailer

Tags: phpmailer

How can i send empty mail with phpmailer i.e. with only attachment files and empty body?
I have send mail with empty $mail->Body="" but mail could not be sent it says 'Message body empty' although i have attached a file.

Answer (score 1):

Before sending a message with an empty body, set `AllowEmpty` to true (see [source code](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) function `preSend`):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
```

Comment: Thanks .But i have another problem,in gmail reply box clicking on reply gives the recipient email id'gabdc@gmail.com(george@gmail.com)' my little code is $mail->UserName="george@gmail.com" ; $mail->Password="" ; $mail->FromName="gabdc@gmail.com" any idea how to remove "(george@gmail.com)" from the recipient id that is 'gabdc@gmail.com(george@gmail.com)'

Comment: [In Gmail, review the headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en) which have actually "arrived". Then try to use the email address as `$mail->From` (and some informal `FromName`) and find out if it goes through. Even if PHPMailer sends the correct headers, Gmail might overwrite/add headers for reasons like spam prevention etc. At least one post indicates this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789673/how-to-change-reply-to-and-return-path-header-with-gmail-smtp-in-django

Comment: The default return address of the george@gmail can be changed but cannot be kept empty ,also reply is sent to george@gmail.com instead of gabdc@gmail.com, is there any solution around this problem help.