# EMail Address Being Rewritten During Delivery

Tags: email, bind, postfix-mta

I host email for a number of different domains - lets call one of them myuser@receiver.com. Lets also pretend my domain is called myserver.com. I receive and store email in a mailbox locally for these domain on mx1.myserver.com. I am having an odd sporadic email issue which I feel must stem from a misconfiguration or setup on my part. This problem only occurs when a 3rd party acts as a forwarder (intermediary), receiving the email for myuser@receiver.com but sending it on to myuser@www.myserver.com. The exerts below are directly from the email message source.

An email is sent by someone to one of my clients. Its received by an intermediary.

```
Received: from email.sender.com (the.sender.com [123.123.123.123])
  by the.forwarder.com (8.14.5+Sun/8.14.5) with SMTP id x12XXXxX123456
  for <myuser@receiver.com>; Thu, 5 Mar 2015 13:23:22 GMT
```

That intermediary then forwards the email to my server, but for some odd reason readdresses it.

```
Received: from the.forwarder.com (the.forwarder.com [234.234.234.234])
  by mx1.myserver.com (smtpd) with ESMTPS id 1234X123X1
  for <myuser@www.myserver.com>; Thu,  5 Mar 2015 08:27:11 -0500 (EST)
```

Why is the.forwarder.com (intermediary) rewriting the domain of the recipient on this message?

Answer (score 0):

Some outgoing SMTP servers are known to re-write the headers on outgoing messages, and change the sender's address in `From:` line to the email address of the user that is authenticating.  Gmail is notorious for doing this.  See [How to change reply-to and return-path header with gmail smtp in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789673/how-to-change-reply-to-and-return-path-header-with-gmail-smtp-in-django) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mti2935. It isn't so much that the from machine is changing. The real problem is the To/For/recipient address has changed domains. This makes delivery to a mailbox on my machine impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was caused by CNAME records in DNS. There were CNAME records that were present mainly for virtual hosting of web services. This would be something like CNAME record of receiver.com points to www.myserver.com (since they share the same IP address). This had the effect of making secondary mail delivery servers address mail to www.myserver.com instead of the intended receiver.com. To fix this I removed the CNAME record and created an A record to the actual IP address.